# Producing array of which its elements are indices

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove values from a large data set that are inconsistent in my analysis.

Here is the current method i'm started with.

For example, lets say I have an array `a` that consist of an number of elements.

```
a = [30, 40, 200, 324, 8, 67, 789, 9, 567, 2143, 13]
idx = [(i,value) for i,value in enumerate(a) if value<=10]

print idx
>>> [(4, 8), (7, 9)]
```

How do i go about to where I can only just create an array that consist of only its indices

```
print idx
>>> [4, 8]
```

Comment: Should be `[4, 7]`.

Comment: Surely you want `[4, 7]`, not `[4, 8]`?

Comment: You have a *list*! A **list**.

Answer (score 2):

Don't include the value in the comprehension result:

```
idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v <= 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just only use the index:

```
>>> a = [30, 40, 200, 324, 8, 67, 789, 9, 567, 2143, 13]
>>> idx = [i for i, value in enumerate(a) if value<=10]
>>> idx
[4, 7]
```